# C# Can't get values from Listview items

Tags: c#, xml, listview

I'm trying to get Values from clicked items in my Listview but for some reason I can't access any variables from my class.

Here is my listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvGames" Margin="0,29,583.8,-0.2" SelectionChanged="MySelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="149" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Class which is attached to the Listview:

```
namespace GameLauncher.Classes
{
    class Game
    {
        public bool CheckBoxes { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Path { get; set; }

        public int time { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SelectionChanged event:

```
private void MySelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Selected: " + e.AddedItems[0]);
}
```

This SelectionChanged event returns the right class path `GameLauncher.Classes.Game`
But I can't acces `e.AddedItems[0].Name;` for example. Why can't I access any variables from my Game class from here? I also tried `lvGames.SelectedItems[0].Name` wich didn't work either. The only options I have are Equals, GetHashCode, GetType and ToString.

I hope someone knows what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks for reading/helping!

Comment: I think you need to cast `e.AddedItems[0]` to `Game`

Comment: I was just gonna write the same as @JRLambert. Casting is the solution.

Comment: @JRLambert Can you give an example how to cast `e.AddedItems[0]` to `Game`?

Comment: Another approach is to bind ItemsSource and SelectedItem.

Comment: Nevermind I got it! It would be nice if you could place it into an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SelectionChangedEventArgs.AddedItems returns an IList. You need to cast to game. So you need to do:

```
Game game = e.AddedItems[0] as Game;
MessageBox.Show("Selected: " + game.Name);
```